# Integral depending on a constant

Tags: real-analysis, integration

My question is how to count
$\int\limits_{x^2+ y^2+ z^2 < x^{\frac{1}{3}}} x^p dx dy dz$ depending on a constant $p \in R$ . I think I should use the theorem of changing varibles in Lebesgue integral and tried with a spherical substitution, but things I got are not computable. Could somebody help me, maybe trying to find another substitution, more suitable for this particular problem? Thank you in advance.